# How to get all alphabetic letters in codeigniter from DB? PHP, MySQL, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using this to get all letters to create alphabetic list:
`SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1) AS letter FROM games ORDER BY letter asc`
Everything OK. But then I try to pass it to codeigniter, it fails (tryed) several variants:

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select("SUBSTRING(title,1,1) AS letter");
$this->db->order_by("letter", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get('games');
```

also this one:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(title,1,1) AS letter ORDER BY letter");
$query = $this->db->get('games');
```

All the time I'm getting:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS letter FROM (`games`) ORDER BY `letter` asc' at line 1
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(title, `1`, `1)` AS letter FROM (`games`) ORDER BY `letter` asc
> ```
>
> Filename: E:\wamp\www\gamecenter\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: So you don't see anything wrong with generated query?

Comment: quotes? How can I remove them if they're generated by codeigniter?

Comment: Check CI documentation about how to pass functions and their arguments into query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a second parameter to the select with FALSE

```
$this->db->select("SUBSTRING(title,1,1) AS letter", FALSE); //This way it will not put the ` characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

$result = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(title,1,1) AS letter FROM (`games`) ORDER BY `letter` asc')->result();

I think its help you.